# python success message not printing

Tags: python, django, django-views

i am trying to print a success message after an add operation in my python django project.but the success message is not printing.it prints None.below is my code.what am i doing wrong?

```
def edit_toners_save(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    toner_id = request.POST.get("toner_id")
    toner_model = request.POST.get("toner_model")

    toner_printer_id = request.POST.get("toner_printer")
    toner_printer = Items.objects.get(id=toner_printer_id)

    # issued_to_id = request.POST.get("issued_to")
    # issued_to = Prosecutions.objects.get(id=issued_to_id)

    total_qty = request.POST.get("total_qty")
    Toners_model = Toners(id=toner_id, toner_model=toner_model, toner_printer=toner_printer, total_qty=total_qty)

    Toners_model.save()
    print(messages.success(request, "done"))
    calc_total_qty()
    print(messages.WARNING)
    return redirect('view_toners')
else:
    return redirect('view_toners')[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`messages.success` doesn't return. you are looking for something like `get_messages()`
According to the official doc from django in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.get_messages):

```py
    from django.contrib.messages import get_messages
    storage = get_messages(request)
```

Comment: can you elaborate the usecase in my  scenario.

Comment: your `print(messages.success(request, "done"))` doesn't work becasue `messages.success` will only return None.

Comment: so what should be the code if i want to print success message?

Comment: `print(get_messages(request))` after you call `messages.success`

Comment: i get the below printed after adding the code as suggested <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x0CF4DE20>

Comment: ok let me ask you in this another way.i want to print a message to my html page after the edit operation.how can i do that.i tried printing messages as below using sweetalert <!--- Messages after CRUD operations --->
{% for message in messages %}
    {% if message.tags == 'success' %}
        <script>
            var m= "{{ message }};
            swal("Perfect !", m , "success")
        </script>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<!--- Messages after CRUD operations --->

Comment: `messages = [m.message for m in get_messages(request)]`

Comment: thank you.i have found the solution combining your and some google results.